# Dynamically update Dypgraphs through .xml update

Tags: dygraphs

Currently, updating an index.html through the file status.xml from a mchp.js all is well, but would like to update the var y inside the dynamic-update.html as part of the Dygraphs.

Question: The given format works to dynamically update html formatted data inside the index.html, but will not update the var y of the javascript, also in the index.htm, is their a way to utilize the working format to update var y?

Below are the code snippet from the index.htm, status.xml, and mchp.js:

mchp.js: called by Ajax to update from status.xml to index.htm

```
document.getElementById("NodeTemp1").innerHTML = getXMLValue(xmlData, "NodeTemp1");
```

status.xml: file holding the dynamic variable NodeTemp(1)

```
<NodeTemp1>~NodeTemp(1)~</NodeTemp1>
```

index.htm: Working - dynamically updated variable NodeTemp1

```
<div align="center">Node 1 Temperature: <span id="NodeTemp1">?</span></div>
```

index.htm: Not Working var y not updating

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var data = [];
      var t = new Date();



      var g1 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div_g1"), data,
                          {
                            drawPoints: true,
                            showRoller: true,
                            title: 'Temperature Vs. Time',
                            xlabel: 'Time',
                            ylabel: 'temperature',
                            labels: ['Time', 'Temperature']
                          });
      setInterval(function() {
        var x = new Date();  // current time
        **var y = NodeTemp1; // have tried <div id="NodeTemp1">?</div>**
        data.push([x, y]);
        g1.updateOptions( { 'file': data } );
      }, 1000);

    </script>
```

Comment: The total system is 99% complete and can graph the default data of Math.random(), a constant called with the .xml format, but can not dynamically update the var y inside the Dygraph java script from the .xml format. I have been doing research to solve this problem but have yet found the solution.

Comment: Succinctly: the system grabs a dynamically changing value, due to a server side process, in a .xml file and updates html content which results in a changing number in a web browser. Have not been able to utilize the same dynamically updating .xml file with its associated functions to update the var y inside the java script Dygraphs.

Comment: I can tell you that your basic method works (create graph object 'g1' then update with g1.updateOptions), so I suspect a problem with your data format.  Use the developer tools to look at the array called 'data' to ensure that it is formatted correctly.  In chrome, Options->More Tools...->Developer Tools.  Use the debugger to set breakpoints and ensure that your form is correct.  The console will also point out any irregularities in your code, such as dygraphs rendering errors or mismatches in array lengths.